# Twilio : Getting child call sid in android client

Tags: android, python, twilio

Currently I am working on the call cost calculation part for the voice and conference calls.

I am able to get the Twilio price for each call using the call sids through Rest apis(python) .

Now, as I understand, when I make a call from the android client - it will be a inbound call to Twilio server and it has a call sid which I can get at the client side using

```
connection.getParameters().get(Connection.IncomingParameterCallSIDKey);
```

And then the server will make an outbound call to the client or the phone number which is specified as "To" which will have a separate call sid which is child to the above one.

Now my question is how can I get this child call sid ?

Or is there a method to get the child call sid by specifying the parent call sid ?

I need it after the call ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you have the parent call sid then you can get the child calls with the following call.

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
account_sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
auth_token = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

child_calls = client.calls.list(parent_call_sid=PARENT_CALL_SID)
```

Let me know if that helps!